# Windows Server 2003: running mail server

Tags: iis, web-server

I'd like to run my own mail server.

What I want to do is:

- Set up a subdomain (eg. mail.example.com)
- Connect it to my web server.

I already made an MX entry at the domain to mail.example.com, but I can't find out how to do the rest.

I'm running Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6.

Comment: This isn't really a question.  I think it's beyond the scope of SF to provide the amount of training this requires.

Comment: YOU...NEED...PROFESSIONAL...HELP...

but on a serious note this is way to much for a serverfault answer and you should speak to a professional about your situation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to have an MTA (Message Transfer Agent) of some kind on the Windows Server as well as all pertinent ports open and forwarded to the server. A reverse DNS record would also be very helpful. Windows Server 2003 does have an [SMTP engine](http://www.ilopia.com/Articles/WindowsServer2003/EmailServer.aspx) that you can install on it, but be careful or you'll be pwnz0rd 6 ways from Sunday in 2 seconds flat.

Check out [this comparison of mail servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_mail_servers), find one for Windows ([Kerio](http://www.kerio.com/mailserver) is super and really cheap) and knock yourself out with the documentation. Hang out on the forums for that mail server program, read, ask and learn. That's the best way to learn. To quote Nike, "Just do it"

Comment: +1 for "pwnz0rd 6 ways from Sunday."  A highly-accurate and official technical description if I ever saw one.

Comment: Personally, I'm a fan of MailEnable.  Free or cheap depending on features. [sarcasm] If you don't secure it, that's okay.  Who doesn't want to help spammers and get their legitimate mail blocked? [/sarcasm]